# Java Button Layouts and Displays

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

My objective here is to display a message to the console, showing which button I have pressed (the buttons go from 1-6). This is the furthest I have gotten.

**CODE:**

```
public class excercise5_1 extends JFrame {


    public excercise5_1() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Create two panels
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();


        // Add three buttons to each panel
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 1 "));
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 2 "));
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 3 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 4 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 5 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 6 "));


        // Add panels to frame
        add(panel1);
        add(panel2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        excercise5_1 frame = new excercise5_1();
        frame.setTitle(" Exercise 12_1 ");
        frame.setSize(600,75);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I just don't know what to do to make it display "Button 2" if I press it.

Comment: Check out this - [How to write an actionlistener tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't create your JButton's inline -- in the add method parameter. So not `panel1.add(new JButton(...))`,
2. Instead create your JButton on its own line: but rather `JButton myButton = new JButton(...)`; and then `panel1.add(myButton);`
3. Use a for loop to simplify things.
4. Add an ActionListener to your button via its `addActioListener(...)` method, and have the ActionListener print the ActionEvent's getActionCommand() String. The ActionEvent is the parameter passed into the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method.
5. Read the [JButton tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) as it's all spelled out for you there. It appears as if you've read nothing about JButtons yet.

Comment: @Ryan: you're welcome. The most important advice is my last line. You have to delve into the tutorials first even before coming here. Using the tutorials is a learned skill that will get better with practice.